# View log of what happened in IRC while I was offline

Tags: logging, irc

I'm an infrequent user of IRC, currently using [Irssi](http://www.irssi.org) on Ubuntu 12.04, and I follow a channel with activity that is about as infrequent as my own use - but not necessarily with activity at the same time as when I'm there.

Is there a way for me to view a log of what's happened since I was last online (or a log of the last *n* things that happened)?

Comment: If you are not connected to the server, then the only logs that are being made are by the server itself or other clients connected. If you do not have access to these then there is no way to view them. By default, I highly doubt any particular server admin is going to make their server's logs available to the public. You are welcome to ask someone else that was connected to the channel and logging for a copy of their logs. Also, if you do get logs, it will be up to you to parse based on your criteria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you aren't connected to the server, there isn't much you can do.

What you could do is run `irssi` under `screen` (so you can detach/reattach easily) on a machine which you can keep always connected (e.g. a server).

Comment: I feared that I needed a server that was always connected in order to catch everything that's said. I had hoped there was some way to get a chat log from the server, but you can't always get what you want =)

Comment: Using the [Mibbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mibbit) client, it is supposed to be possible to see past messages (if some other Mibbit client user is on the same channel). [It is banned from freenode, though](https://wiki.mibbit.com/index.php/Problem_Networks).